# How to write out sql in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello i am trying to get this into a function `getTableResults`. I am unfamiliar with php.

```
SELECT *
FROM members
INNER JOIN member_details
ON members.member_id=member_details.member_id;
```

I have a similar function i am trying to base it by but i am really unsure as the sql is longer.

```
function getResults($tablename) {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $tablename;
   $mysqlConnection = getSQLConnection();

   $ResultSet = $mysqlConnection->query($sql);
 return $ResultSet;
}
```

---

**Would this be it?**

```
function getResults($tablename) {
   $sql = "SELECT *
           FROM members
           INNER JOIN member_details
           ON members.member_id=member_details.member_id; " . $tablename;
   $mysqlConnection = getSQLConnection();

   $ResultSet = $mysqlConnection->query($sql);
 return $ResultSet;
}
```

Comment: This is actually very basic. Are you sure you haven't tried everything to figure this out?

Comment: PHP knows nothing about sql. You write in SQL in php exactly the same as you would write any other plain-text string.

Comment: I have tried however i am unsure with the first line in the function

Comment: Then you should learn basic PHP syntax: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php  we're here to help, not be your teachers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function getTableResults() {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM members INNER JOIN member_details ON Members.member_id=member_details.member_id";
   $mysqlConnection = getSQLConnection();

   $ResultSet = $mysqlConnection->query($sql);
 return $ResultSet;
}
```

Basically the same, you change your SQL query in the $sql variable.

**Note:** This function does not accept a tablename now, as you had a very specific SQL query.

Answer (score 3):

Check this

```
function getTableResults() {
   $sql = "SELECT *
           FROM members
           INNER JOIN member_details
           ON members.member_id=member_details.member_id";
   $mysqlConnection = getSQLConnection();

   $ResultSet = $mysqlConnection->query($sql);
   return $ResultSet;
}
```

**EDIT:**

After your Edit in the question **`Would this be it`**

**No** because what you are trying is to concatenating the table name in the query..

`details.member_id; " . $tablename;` <- can't do this ..

This will make your query look like `ON members.member_id=member_details.member_id;  members` (*if you send `members` as the $tablename in the parameter*)

Comment: So what this is doing is selecting the table members and joining to the members details where they both match with member_id?

Comment: Might want to fix your edit now; it's definitely incorrect ;)

Comment: I was not specific enough in my comment (my apologies). I meant that your code is correct, but the "My Answer is **Yes**" part isn't.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getTableResults(){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members 
        INNER JOIN member_details
        ON members.member_id=member_details.member_id";

$mysqlConnection = getSQLConnection();
$ResultSet = $mysqlConnection->query($sql);

return $ResultSet;
}
```

Please note that the functions of mysql have been deprecated. mysqli should be used instead. PHP.net [says](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) that mysql's functions will be removed in the future, so you should switch now. In practice, there is very little difference between the code of mysql and the code of mysqli. Please see this site for examples on how to use mysqli: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Just as a heads up, `$mysqlConnection` looks to be a PDO wrapper, not related to the family of `mysql_*` functions (which HAVE been deprecated). Also, a minor typo: assigning to `$mysqlConnection` but using `$mysqliConnection`

Comment: Good catches. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
 <?php

$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123");

// Check connection


 if (mysqli_connect_errno())

      {


 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

  }
// Create database
$sql="SELECT *
FROM members
INNER JOIN member_details

ON members.member_id=member_details.member_id";

if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{

echo "Database my_db created successfully";

  }else{

echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($con);

 }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would end up looking something like this:

```
function getResults($tablename) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members"
           . " INNER JOIN member_details"
           . " ON members.member_id=member_details.member_id";
    $mysqlConnection = getSQLConnection();

    $ResultSet = $mysqlConnection->query($sql);
    return $ResultSet;
}
```